# How to get list of posts from permalinks?

Tags: wp-query, loop, permalinks, query

I am using an API which tracks metrics on parts of my site. The only useful bit it saves though is the URL (permalink).

What is the most efficient way to query up all the posts that match those permalinks, given the fact that I don't have access to the ID's to use `post__in` with `WP_Query`.

Comment: You can query posts based on the permalink slug using `name` parameter.

Comment: can you show me an example which accepts input as an array of slugs? like `['hello-world', 'post-2', 'welcome-post']`, I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: It doesn't accept any array, you need to pass a valid slug to it to query for that post. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this, depending on the permalink structure of your posts. Assuming the post slug is part of the permalink structure, you can get the post slug from the post URL and fetch the corresponding post by using `WP_Query` with the `name`-parameter. Let's assume the structure of the URLs is `http://example.com/{post_slug}/`. We can fetch the slug by using [parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and query the posts with that slug:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/my-post/';

$path = parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_PATH ); // Get URL path from URL
$slug = trim( $path, '/' ); // Trim slashes

$posts_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'name' => $slug
) );

if ( $posts_query->have_posts() ) {
    $postid = $posts_query->posts[0]->ID;
}
```

Comment: If I start with an array of permalinks though, such as `['hello-world', 'post-2', 'welcome-post']`, and i do that method, will it do a SQL query for each post? Sorry, I should have clarified -- this will be for quite a few posts and I wanted it to be efficient so I'm not doing an n+1

Comment: It won't, and there's no easy way to do that outside of custom SQL queries.

Comment: Why don't use the https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid every post slug is a single post element right?